# Compare multiple datasets across in SAS

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I am new to SAS

I have multiple datasets with the following variables

- Dataset 1 Subid;visit; flag; date; time
- Dataset 2 Subid;visit; flag; date; time
- Dataset 3 Subid;visit; date; time
- Dataset 4 Subid;visit; date; time

I need to,

1. When flag is present in the dataset compare date and time for the flag across datasets across visits
2. When flag is not present in dataset compare date across mentioned datasets and across visits

Comment: What is your desired output? When you compare dates and times, what should be done?

Comment: Do you want one 4-at-a-time comparison (1:2:3:4) or six pairwise comparisons (1:2., 1:3. 1:4. 2:3. 2:4. 3:4).  Have you written any code? Did you try using `MERGE`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two datasets with the flag and two datasets without the flag. If you simply want a pure comparison of two datasets, `proc compare` will produce a report for you that compares variables with each other.

Example data:

```
data dataset1;
    input subid visit flag date:date9. time:time.;
    format date date9. time time.;
    datalines;
1 1 1 01JAN2022 00:00
2 2 0 01JAN2022 01:00
;
run;

data dataset2;
    input subid visit flag date:date9. time:time.;
    format date date9. time time.;
    datalines;
1 1 1 01JAN2022 00:00
2 2 1 03JAN2022 02:00
;
run;
```

Code:

```
proc sort data=dataset1;
    by subid visit;
run;

proc sort data=dataset2;
    by subid visit;
run;

proc compare base=dataset1 compare=dataset2;
    id subid visit;
    var date time;
run;
```

[image]

You can produce a dataset of only the differences as well.

```
proc compare base    = dataset1 
             compare = dataset2 
             out     = compare
             outnoequal
             noprint
             ;

    id subid visit;
    var date time;
run;
```